# Cannot understand why C pointer is not working

Tags: c, pointers

Forgive me if this is a simple error, but I am just learning C at the moment and I just made a trivial program to get a grasp of pointers.

I have a simple piece of code that yields an output I expect

```
int x = 4;
int *p;
p = &x;
printf("%d\n\n",*p);

//output is 4 as expected
```

But when I try to do the same with a char array even though I follow the same logic...

```
char x[] = "Hello, Stack Overflow!";
char *p[];
p = &x;
printf("%s\n\n",*p);

//this gives me an error when compiling as follows
//
// run.c:15: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[1]’ from type ‘char (*)[23]’
```

Comment: Actually, this question is was better than usual beginner-C-pointer questions. +1.

Comment: When you type "under" without stand then you're trying to do it too fast.  Pointers take time.

Comment: @HansPassant: Actually, once you grasp the concept of RAM, you pretty much get the understanding of pointers for free. The C declaration syntax; Now that's a different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple errors. First, `char *p[]` doesn't declare a pointer-to-an-array (as you think it does) - it rather declares an array of char pointers.

Second, since `x` is an array, `&x` will evaluate to the same numerical value as `x` (since arrays cannot be passed by value, only by pointer, they decay into pointers when passed to a function). What you need to do is rather

```
const char *x = "Hello SO!";
const char **p = &x;
printf("%s\n", *p);
```

This is the easy solution (making the string literal, that is, an array of `char`s, decay into a pointer). There's another solution that requires a bit more thinking. From the compiler error message, you can see that the type of `&x` is `char (*)[]`. So what you have to declare here is a pointer-to-array:

```
char x[] = "Hello SO!"; // x is a char array
char (*p)[] = &x; // p is a pointer to a char array
printf("%s\n", *p); // printf accesses *p, so it prints the underlying char array - correct!
```

Comment: I don't think the second paragraph is right. The value of x is the array "Hello, Stack Overflow!", it isn't a pointer. Arrays and pointers aren't the same. See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html. Of course, inside of printf they're the same, for the reasons you mention. But not in the scope we're looking at.

Comment: @nes1983 I was just explaining to another answer provider, dreamzor, that arrays ain't pointers. Neither do state this in my answer. I don't see your point - what's the problem?

Comment: This works perfectly, but to make sure I get the idea:

- First line creates a pointer that points to an automatically allocated memory location which now contains "Hello SO!", right?
- Second line creates a pointer to a pointer, hence the double asterisk?
- Third line, I of course get :D

Comment: @h2co3 well, you do write "since x is an array, &x will evaluate to the same numerical value as x". That's misleading. I'd rephrase. Perhaps:
printf("%s\n", x) and printf("%s\n", &x) are the same.

Comment: @nes1983 Yes, that also works. Why? Because when passed to a function, both `x` and `&x` *decay into* the same pointer, thes just have different types, both of which can be converted to a char pointer, that is expected by `printf()`.

Comment: This throws away array length information. Unnecessarily. Additionally, somebody might try to `free` that thing, so I really see no reason to declare `x` as pointer. Especially when the OP asks for an an array and a pointer to an array. It's bad advice to beginners to say "just use a pointer instead of an array and the compiler will shut up. There closely related anyway."

Comment: @bitmask now can I also have some actual suggestions for improving the answer? Or are you just criticizing without trying to help?

Comment: I believe I gave you a suggestion: Don't recommend weakening the original array to a pointer.

Comment: Thanks H2CO3, you've been immensely helpful!

Answer (score 2):

To create a pointer to an array you must explicitly say so, as the subscript operator takes precedence over the dereferencing operator.

```
char x[] = "Hello, there";
char (*p)[sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)] = &x;
```

What you are saying here is that dereferencing first and *then* applying the subscript `(*p)[i]` must yield a `char`. As others have stated your code declares an array to pointers to `char`.

Comment: @H2CO3: If you preferred me not pointing out problems with posts, you could say so instead of answering with such patronising remarks.

Comment: I don't prefer not pointing out problems, I just can't tolerate the agressive way you approached it.

Comment: @H2CO3: I'm honestly sorry if you took it the wrong way. I didn't intend to upset you.

Comment: OK, I see, I calmed down, sorry, mee too.

Answer (score 1):

`char *p[]` means p is an array of character pointers, not a pointer to an array. You should keep p `char *p`, then it'll work.

Comment: Sorry for the editing. That doesn't work for me, it gives me this error:

run.c: In function ‘main’:
run.c:15: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

and also...

Segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

Change `char *p[]` to `char p[]` or `char *p`. `char *p[]` equals to `char **p`.

Comment: `char *p[] equals to char **p` is simply not true. ***Arrays are not pointers.***

Comment: Actually it does equal, if you don't care about the scope. Arrays **are** pointers, the `arr[0]` is equal to `*arr` and the `arr[i]` == `*(arr + i)`. So you are simply not right :)

Comment: you're pwning yourself by your 'arrays are pointers' statement. [You better just relax and read the C FAQ.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html)

Comment: Of course they are not **same**, but really, for the OP they are the same in this situation. Please, be more polite. We all are searching for the truth here :)

Comment: the point(er) is **exactly** the difference between arrays and pointers. OP's code didn't work because he assumed arrays and pointers are the same - in particular, he thought that the address of an array variable would be the same as the address of a pointer variable, which is not true, and it caused confusion. Don't confuse OP even more by telling him the exact opposite of the truth.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char x[] = "Hello, Stack Overflow!";
    char *p;
    int len = strlen(x);

    p = malloc(len * sizeof(char) +1);
    strcpy(p,x);
    printf("%s\n\n",p);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`x` here is a pointer by itself (a pointer to the first element of the array). If you put just `char *p` and `p = x`, it should work.